# Filter role based users in c# linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-6, iqueryable

we have multiple roles in our system and a user can have multiple roles assigned to it
and everything is managed custom. We are not using identity or so.

I am sending my api request with some roles like "guest", "admin". 
Api should only returns users having these roles

this is how I am filtering users
`List<string> roles` -> this is a variable that have role names 
coming from front-end suppose "admin"

roles = "admin" -> but can have more roles

UserRoleMappings is navigation property that holds user id and 
role id combination to save roles of particular user

now while getting all users, I would like to filter them so that

```
query.Where(user => user.UserRoleMappings.Any(urm => roles.Contains(urm.UserRole.Name)));
```

This query is fetching users having roles "admin" + "guests" as I have
applied contains. But i need users which only have "admin" role

beacuse

```
user

1  user1
2 user2

role
1 admin
2 guest

userMapping
1 1
1 2
2 1
```

Api should only return user2 but it is also returning user1. This methid should be generic and should work formultiple roles

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Do you have the navigational property to go from a role (to a mapping) to a user? Maybe it would help if you posted your entities.

Comment: From your `userMapping` table it look like both users have Admin role. So please make sure data is correct and also specify which column holds which id.

Comment: Assuming :( `userMapping` (or is it `UserRoleMappings`???) has rows with user, role then you have 1 -> 1 and 2 -> 1 so both users have admin role.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use select and Where,
query.Select(user => user.UserRoleMappings.where(urm => roles.Contains(urm.UserRole.Name))).toList();

now your where clause will return only Matched Element

Comment: Wouldn't this return List<IEnumerable<string>> whereas OP want's a list of users?

Answer (score 0):

If you need users that only have the admin role and no other roles you can do

```
var adminUsers = query
    .Where(user => user.UserRoleMappings.All(urm => urm.UserRole.Name == "admin"));
```

because if "all" of their roles are named "admin" it necessarily is the only role they have.